# What does the SSL error "protocol is shutdown" mean?

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

[One of my users](https://github.com/celery/py-amqp/issues/325) is getting this error when attempting to write to a socket.

Unfortunately, I can't help him since I can't find anything that describes the error, if it is recoverable or not and how to handle it.
There's no correlation in the logs of Celery and RabbitMQ. Only the client reports a problem (we think) so we assume it's py-amqp that is causing the issue.

Comment: This kind of error is raised when the SSL wrapper tries to write to a closed TCP connection. It is usually related to connection problems, firewalls or SSL interception.

Comment: How do I recover from it?

Comment: Diagnose and fix the network problem, but that is out of scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: That's not what I was asking. I'm asking if I can close the socket and attempt to reconnect when this error occurs.

Comment: You can, but I can't guarantee that will help a lot.

Comment: Please explain how I should do that! Any network related issue is out of scope for SO and for a solution in code (like exception handling…) there is something important missing: your code.

Comment: My code is available at the repository.

Comment: You can answer the question by explaining what the error means, provide a reliable source (documentation or otherwise) and explain how should we treat the error. Should we raise the exception as we do now? Should we close the connection first and then raise the exception? Should we attempt to reconnect?

Comment: You have collected a lot of reputation already. It is rather surprising that you don't know the rule that the code to reproduce the error has to be included in the question itself.